# Table layout in android (span/shrink)?

Tags: android, html, layout, android-tablelayout

I want this special table layout:

[image: Layout of table]

In my current layout the cells that are shorter are at the same size like the cells with the long text:

[image: wrong layout]

How do have to do it?

It should look like the first picture.

Comment: I think that part of what a table layout is supposed to do is give you columns that line up.  You want columns that don't line up.  I'm not sure its the right thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be better ways of doing this, I actually haven't used TableLayout before, but the XML below gives the basic layout that you asked for:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Text"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:text="Text that is longer than other cells" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Text" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="Text" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yojimbo, you are right, however if you use

> android:layout_weight

you must remember about replacing (in this special case) android:layout_width="**wrap_content**" with

> android:layout_width="**0dp**" .

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) you have a nice reference.